# Generate HighChart Colors Before Drawing Chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, colors, react-highcharts

My React app is plotting multiple series on a single Highcharts chart using `highcharts-react-official` where each series is automatically assigned a color by Highcharts.

For each series, there is a corresponding button on the webpage that needs to be the same color as its series in the Highcharts chart.

In order to synchronize the chart series colors with the button colors, is it possible to use a Highcharts function to generate these colors before even rendering the Highchart component? This pre-generated array of color strings will then be passed into the button and Highchart components.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13691 (passing an array of hex values as `color:` to the chart)

Comment: @ChrisG Almost! Do we know the default set of colors that is being used by Highcharts? I looked at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/js/Extensions/Themes but can't identify the default theme being used in Highcharts v16.x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an array with colors before creating a chart and use it in options:

```
const colors = [...];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colors,
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xco2kas5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors